# resize simple objects to specific sizes

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to load simple objects into the empty world of gazebo (box, cylinder and sphere.) and scale their sizes to specific values (say x = 2,y=1,z=3 for a box). The below image can give a better picture.

[image: image description]

Am able to scale using the scale tool available, but am not able to scale it to specific values, that can be reflected by the x,y and z from the properties on the left panel. Any direction on how I can scale it to specific values?

Note : When I scale the object using the scaling tool to any size, the properties values does not change at all from 1, for XYZ.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16774/resize-simple-objects-to-specific-sizes/) by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Be sure you upgrade to a version of Gazebo which is currently supported, that's either Gazebo 7 or 8. Then you could do it like this:

1. Insert a simple shape into simulation
2. Right-click -> `Edit model`
3. Double click -> Open the `Visual` tab
4. Expand `visual`
5. Under `geometry`, type in the desired values
6. Repeat 3~5 for collision
7. `File` -> `Exit model editor`
8. `Save and Exit`

Voila :)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2017-07-17**:
Thank you for your answer. am currently working with gazebo 2.2.6, and I was able to locate geometry, under the size tab, under visual in the properties on the left. That still doesn't change the size. It gets back to 1 each.

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2017-07-17**:
as shown in the picture above, I did alter the values of x,y and z. But how do I get them to reflect on the object?

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2017-07-17**:
in the properties, I can see 2 visual tabs. I tried editing both, but am not able to see them change permanently. The moment I click outside and view the values again, it's reset to default.

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2017-07-17**:
am not in a state to upgrade, since am working with indigo and 14.04 trusty

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-07-17**:
Gazebo 7 is supported on Trusty, this tutorial should help: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-07-17**:
The only option on Gazebo 2 is to manually write SDF files with the simple shapes in the sizes you want.

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2017-07-17**:
thank you for your help. It worked.! Gazebo7

**Comment by [Tonystark124](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1321/tonystark124/) on 2017-07-18**:
@chapulina I was not able to connect indigo and gazebo7, thus am working with gazebo 2 now. Can you please point me towards the right direction of writing sdf files for sizes and shapes?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-07-18**:
Sorry to hear that, Gazebo 7 would really be the best solution right now. I'm afraid you might run into many other problems with Gazebo 2. In any case, this tutorial should help you write the models: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_model